# PHPStorm can't find MySQL Workbbench model in project structure

Tags: osx-lion, mysql-workbench, phpstorm

I'm using MySQL Workbench for database modeling and I wanted to put the .mwb file in my project structure. I managed to do that (the file is there) but somehow it doesn't show up in the project structure. I tried to show hidden files with "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE"(I'm using OSX) but nothing happened. I need to share this with my team mate but i can't even add it to git. The IDE is PHP Storm(if this helps).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm doesn't work with .mwb files and can't recognize them.

Comment: i know PHP storm does not work with mdw files. I wanted only to be added to the project. I've found the solution, i didn't had root permission on that folder and that is why i couldn't see the file. Thank you.